# Java WebStart does not install in Windows7

Tags: java, windows-7-x64, java-web-start

My Webstart Application works well with Windows XP. 
It should install itself and put a desktop-shortcut-icon on the desktop:
http://www.lehrer-werkzeug.de/start/lehwe.jnlp

Under Windows 7 the Application starts, but there is no icon on the desktop, nothing in the start-menu. There is nothing shown in the Java-Control-Panel.
The same problems occur on other computers with window 7.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: I am not familar with Java Webstart, but I think the folder structure for user profile data in Windows 7 is different to Windows XP.

Comment: what jre version do you use? Can it be that user is running 64bits version of browser and the jre installation is 32bits or the other way around?

Comment: `<?xml version=“1.0“ encoding=“UTF-8“?>`  I am pretty sure those 'smart quotes' are not valid UTF-8 or XML.  Be sure to validate it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Answer (score 1):

We have a 'null result' on this Windows 7 box.

[image]

### Output.

#### Console

```
Java Web Start 1.6.0
Using JRE version 1.7.0_09 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\..
----------------------------------------------------
..
----------------------------------------------------
Hallo Welt! Hier ist LEHRER-WERKZEUG(9.73)
0 Assertions sind aus!
1 WebStart
2 Security-Exception: Kein Logfile möglich
3 Linux?= false
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### access denied ("java.awt.AWTPermission" "createRobot")
```

(I made a local copy of the JNLP that kept the code sand-boxed.)

#### Properties applet

[OS properties](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=os.arch%2Cos.name%2Cos.version&format=TSV) for this box.

```
Name    Value
os.arch x86
os.name Windows 7
os.version  6.1
```

### Conclusion

Whatever the problem is, it is not the OS version.